# Shuffling an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, int, shuffle

I'm trying to create a method to randomly shuffle a array of primitives using a Arraylist. I was wondering if the `.get();` method was the proper method to use on my Arraylist where on a normal array in a for loop it would just be `array[j];` where j is the value in the for loop. Also, I'm not too familiar with Math.random(); and needed some help implementing it in this situation.

```
public static void selectionShuffle(int[] values) {

    ArrayList<Integer> temp=new ArrayList<Integer>(52);

    int rando=(int)Math.random()*52+1;
    for(int counter=0;counter<temp.size();counter++){
        temp.set(rando,(Integer)counter);
    }

    for(int counter=0;counter<values.length;counter++){
        values[counter]=temp.get(counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: [`Collections.shuffle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List))

Comment: Tariq: When you do this: ArrayList<Integer> temp=new ArrayList<Integer>(52); What are you intending to do? Specifically when you put that 52 in those brackets, what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Collections.shuffle(temp);` is what you need

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29

What you may want to do is after creating the `ArrayList`, run a for-loop to add 52 values:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){ 
    temp.add(i);
}
```

Then do this:

```
Collections.shuffle(temp);
```

Print out the result to confirm

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation should ensure that every index is set at least once. Your `temp.set(rando,(Integer)counter)` sets a **random index** to the value of counter. Also, you must change the value of `rando` with every iteration of the loop.

`Math.random()`

> returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to
>   0.0 and **less than 1.0.**

as per [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()), so when you multiply by 52.0 you get a value between 0 and 51.9 inclusive. When cast to an integer it is truncated to the floor of its value, giving you a range of 0 - 51 inclusive, or the size of your array.